# Convert multiple .rtf (or .pages/.doc) files to .html on Mac

Tags: html

I have about 100 .rtf files with images, formatted text etc. How can I convert all these files to .html, so all the images and formatting will remain?

Comment: do you want an HTML code to do that or just a convertor program..?

Comment: Actually, I've already managed to do it. Thanks ;)

Comment: Would you mind posting the answer then so others (like myself) can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specially for Brandon.

I solved it easily - just copy/paste. I haven't found another way...